# How to send and receive parameters to/from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

IN THE LAST PART I WROTE THE working solution: 
I have this stored procedure in SQL Server :

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureName]
    @v nvarchar(10),
    @L NVarChar(2)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT B,M,V
    FROM XXXX
    WHERE V = @v and L = @L
END
```

and I am passing the parameters but I cannot retrieve the `SELECT` part I need to retrieve B,M,V of `Select B,M,V` also

```
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", cnn);
Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@v", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = v;
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@L", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2).Value = lo;

if (Cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
   Cmd.Connection.Open();
}

Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

THIS IS THE WOKING SOLUTION THANKS TO THE HELP I GOT HERE :

```
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", cnn);
Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@v", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = v;
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@L", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2).Value = lo;

if (Cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
   Cmd.Connection.Open();
}

using (SqlDataReader reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   if (reader.HasRows)
   {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
         ret = new MYCLASS();
            ret.B = reader.GetString(0);
            ret.M = reader.GetString(1);
            ret.V = reader.GetString(2);
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Use ExecuteReader() insted of ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Look up [`SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to make use of **[SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** to achieve this. Also make use of `using` block to ensure the connection object is closed and disposed correctly.

From **[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

> To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside of a using block, as shown in the following code fragment. Doing so ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block.

You can change your code to something like:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString")) {
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", con)) {

//Params here

con.Open();

using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        var bValue = reader.GetString(0);
        //Same for the next two values
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: GetOrdinal will return you the index of the column (I.e. a number) and not the actual value of the column, so calling it "bValue" is a little misleading.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for pointing that out, I wrote it on the fly and haven't tested it and that was what came to my mind at the time. However your are correct, I should've done something like `var bValue = reader["B"];`

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, now if you pay close attention to your code you're not using the correct method for your procedure. This can be easily achieved with:

`ExecuteReader` Since you're only reading from your database.

instead of:

`ExecuteNonQuery` which is commonly used for `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE` statements